# How to put different request's response in the same document with nodejs and request?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, get, request

Hi I want to put different request's response in the same document. I have this document:

```
var result = {google:"", twitter:"", facebook:""}
```

I want to do different GET requests to these sites (google.com, Facebook.com, twitter.com) and put all the result in the correspondent field.
I tried with nested callbacks but in this way i have to do first the google call, then the twitter etc like this:

```
Request({
        url:first_url,
      },function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
             request.log(err);
        }else{
           risultato.google = body;
           Request({
        url:second_url,
      },function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
             request.log(err);
        }else{
           risultato.facebook = body;
           Request({
        url:third_url,
      },function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
             request.log(err);
        }else{
           risultato.twitter = body;
           console.log(result);
        }
       });
     }
   });
  }
 });
```

So i have to know how to do all the requests in parallel, and when i have all the request's response in the result object i have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

async.parallel({
  google: function(cb) {
    request("https://google.com", function(err, resp, data) {
      cb(err, data)
    })
  },
  facebook: function(cb) {
    request("https://facebook.com", function(err, resp, data) {
      cb(err, data)
    })
  },
  twitter: function(cb) {
    request("https://twitter.com", function(err, resp, data) {
      cb(err, data)
    })
  },
}, function(err, results) {
     console.log(err, results);
     //results is now equals to {google: "", facebook: "". twitter: ""}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `async` would be to use the Promise API. There's a `request-promise` npm library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) that returns a Promise for each request. We can send requests for each URL, then simply call Promise.All on the list of Promises:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yelp.com'];

// List of Promises that resolve the original URL and the content
const resultPromises = urls.map(url => {
    return request(url).then(response => ({ url, response }));
});

Promise.all(resultPromises)
    .then(results => {
        // results is an array containing the URL and response for each URL
        console.log(results);
    });
```